# SqlAlchemy ORM and aggregate functions

Tags: python, postgresql, orm, sqlalchemy

I am using sqlalchemy ORM to get data from Postgresql database and I am wonderer how you are doing a complex query with sqlalchemy ORM like this one :

```
select table1.name, Array(select name from table2 join table3 using(id) where param1=6949)
from table1
where param1=6949
```

Comment: I think the term you are probably looking for is "correlated subqueries": http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/tutorial.html#correlated-subqueries I would give you an example, but from what you wrote I'm not sure what query you are trying to make and what the structure of your data is.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [ARRAY constructor](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ARRAY-CONSTRUCTORS) with [generic functions](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/functions.html). Depending on how you've mapped your tables, either as ORM models or `Table`s:

```
# ORM mappings here
stmt = session.query(Table2.name).\
    join(Table3, Table2.id == Table3.id).\
    filter_by(param1=Table1.param1)

query = session.query(Table1.name,
                      func.array(stmt.as_scalar())).\
    filter_by(param1=6949)
```

The ARRAY constructor expects a subquery producing a single column. The subquery must be used as an expression and also be removed from the list of FROM objects, which can be done using [`as_scalar()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.as_scalar).

A concrete example:

```
In [2]: class Table1(MagicBase):
   ...:     name = Column(Unicode)
   ...:     param1 = Column(Integer)
   ...:     

In [3]: class Table2(MagicBase):
   ...:     name = Column(Unicode)
   ...:     

In [4]: class Table3(MagicBase):
   ...:     param1 = Column(Integer)
   ...:     

In [5]: stmt = session.query(Table2.name).\
   ...:     join(Table3, Table2.id == Table3.id).\
   ...:     filter_by(param1=Table1.param1)
   ...: 
   ...: query = session.query(Table1.name,
   ...:                       func.array(stmt.as_scalar())).\
   ...:     filter_by(param1=6949)
   ...: 

In [6]: print(query)
SELECT table1.name AS table1_name, array((SELECT table2.name 
FROM table2 JOIN table3 ON table2.id = table3.id 
WHERE table3.param1 = table1.param1)) AS array_1 
FROM table1 
WHERE table1.param1 = %(param1_1)s
```